# Getting an error when trying to plot a histogram

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
ValueError: Multi-dimensional indexing (e.g. `obj[:, None]`) is no longer supported. 
Convert to a numpy array before indexing instead.
```

```
plt.style.use("seaborn")
fig, ax =plt.subplots(3,1, figsize=(15,20))  


sns.histplot(x = df["instrumentalness"].to_numpy(), kde=True, ax=ax[0], color="navy", bins=15);
ax[0].set_xlabel("instrumentalness",fontsize=15);

sns.histplot(x = df["liveness"].to_numpy(), kde=True, ax=ax[1], color="darkorange", bins=15);
ax[1].set_xlabel("liveness",fontsize=15);

sns.histplot(x = df["speechiness"].to_numpy(), kde=True, ax=ax[2], color="firebrick", bins=15);
ax[2].set_xlabel("speechiness",fontsize=15);
```

matplotlib: 3.5.1
pandas: 2.1.1
statsmodels: 0.13.5

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.